# Row rename after cbind matrix

Tags: r, rename

```
CPT = cbind(CPTa$Seller,DisCPT,DisSellCPT)
CPT

         [,1]     [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]       [,8]
[1,]     1715 10656.10       0.00   14642.54   21035.93 1268625.67 1274133.34 1242871.98
[2,]     2432 10655.38   14642.54       0.00   13977.05 1280809.90 1286142.97 1254953.24
[3,]     9991 10649.17   21035.93   13977.05       0.00 1289479.20 1295040.50 1263758.70
[4,] 29823984 10654.64 1268625.67 1280809.90 1289479.20       0.00   27399.00   30229.96
[5,]   785748 10654.76 1274133.34 1286142.97 1295040.50   27399.00       0.00   33043.67
[6,] 29824531 10659.36 1242871.98 1254953.24 1263758.70   30229.96   33043.67       0.00
```

I want to change the

```
[,1] to "Seller"
[,2] to "DC"
[,3] to [,8] to the values of column.
```

How to do I do that?

Comment: You can use `row.names(CPT) <- yourvectorofvalues`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can *cbind* with names, compare the outputs of below two examples:

```
cbind(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] 21.0    6
# [2,] 21.0    6

cbind(myName1 = mtcars$mpg, myName2 = mtcars$cyl)
#      myName1 myName2
# [1,]    21.0       6
# [2,]    21.0       6
```